# Нужна ли запятая перед словосочетанием "в попытке"?

Tags: пунктуация, члены-предложения

**Не стоит себя заставлять в попытке угнаться за здоровьем**.

Является ли здесь сказуемым "заставлять в попытке угнаться"? И нужно ли ставить запятую перед "в попытке", если это не так?

Comment: Заголовок не соответствует тексту. И вообще странный вопрос о запятой..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном сообщении я увидел два вопроса, изложенных последовательно. Отвечать буду по аналогии.

1. Определение сказуемого. Предложенный Вами вариант не является верным, потому что второстепенные члены предложения могут входить в состав сказуемого только в частных случаях (если интересны все случаи, при которых сказуемое приобретает такой "нестандартный" вид, то уведомите меня в комментариях), ярким примером которых является наличие фразеологизма либо устойчивого сочетания. Здесь же его роль выполняет только СГС "не стоит заставлять себя",  где "не стоит" — глагол-связка со значением запрета, а "заставлять себя" — инфинитив ("себя" также входит в состав сказуемого, так как имеет связь с его составляющим), несущий лексическое значение. Отмечу, что предложение **безличное** и **неполное**, так как лексическое значение всё же изъяснено не полностью и связано с контекстом всего текста. Зависимые слова, по ошибке определённые Вами как части сказуемого, образуют цельное обстоятельство причины и, соответственно, отвечают на вопрос "почему?".
2. Постановка запятой. Учитывая тот факт, что спорный член предложения всё же является обстоятельством, то в теории появляется возможность поставить запятую на основании обособленности оборота, который несёт дополнительное значение причинности и связан по смыслу со сказуемым в данном предложении и, как я написал выше, с контекстом. Однако она всё же больше относится к авторским знакам, поэтому нормативнее было бы оставить всё как есть.

Answer (score 2):

То, что начинается словами "в попытке" к сказуемому не относится: это обстоятельственный оборот со значением причины. Сам по себе обособления он не требует (если упростить: не надо усердствовать в своей попытке), однако данное предложение *неполное*: в нем пропущено оставленное в предшествующем контексте действие (**что** заставлять **делать**?), которое подразумевается, и его можно заместить постановкой тире:

> [Вы намерены голодать целый месяц?] Не стоит себя заставлять [делать это] - в
>   попытке угнаться за здоровьем.